# passwordless ssh to localhost in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I seem to be unable to set up a passwordless ssh connection to localhost, and I'm not sure why.

In `~/.ssh` I have `id_rsa`, `authorized_keys`, `id_rsa.pub` and `known_hosts`

```
diff authorized_keys id_rsa
```

returns nothing

```
ls -al
```

gives

```
-rw-------  1 long long 1675 Jun  3 02:24 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 long long 1675 Jun  3 02:23 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 long long  438 Jun  3 02:23 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 long long  444 Jun  3 02:57 known_hosts
```

The permissions of the `.ssh` folder are

```
drwx------  2 long long 4096 Jun  3 03:29 .ssh
```

The permissions of my home folder are

```
drwxr-xr-x 23 long long 4096 Jun  3 02:23 long
```

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I changed `PermitEmptyPasswords` to `yes`

And finally, the verbose output of

```
ssh -v localhost
```

is

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/long/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/long/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/long/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 
Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'long'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: 
<implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: 
<implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 
SHA256:XK9dVu0tdSA4YSbcifizhFhigKZU2LZl+W91Eesdimw
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/long/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/long/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: long@long-MS-7885-Invalid-entry-length-16-
Fixed-up-to-11
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
long@localhost's password:
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The authorized keys are public, not private. So `diff authorized_keys id_rsa` should _not_ return nothing, though `diff authorized_keys id_rsa.pub` could reasonably be empty

Answer (score 1):

The `PermitEmptyPasswords` setting allows SSH to accept passwords which are blank, but that does not mean SSH won't prompt for a password:

> PermitEmptyPasswords - When password authentication is allowed, it specifies whether the server allows login to accounts with empty password strings.  The default is no. - `man sshd_config`

To allow logging in without a password you need to set up public key authentication. As mentioned by Fox, your output of the command `diff authorized_keys id_rsa` suggests you only have your private SSH key in your authorized_keys file; That file should not have any private keys. You can run `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to replace that with your public key instead.

Then you can get rid of that blank password :)

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you for your help!